# I want to plot Gender (male/female) proportion of titanic dataset in pie chat using matplotlib, showing percentage representation of male and female

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

`url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Geoyi/Cleaning-Titanic-Data/master/titanic_original.csv'`

`titanic = pd.read_csv(url)`

I want a pie chart that shows proportion of males and females and gender not registered

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure you've read the guidelines for posting questions. As a rule of thumbs, post data and the attemps you've done to solve or answer your questions. Do not assume that the community will do the work for you.

Comment: Show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can take inspiration from this:

```
def label_function(val):
    return f'{val / 100 * len(df):.0f}\n{val:.0f}%'

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(10, 5))

df.groupby('sex').size().plot(kind='pie',autopct=label_function,textprops={'fontsize': 20},
                                  colors=['r', 'b'], ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

[image]